# starting and running plex media server?

Tags: configuration, services, webserver, plex, mediaserver

How do I start `plex` and navigate to its configuration page?

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sudo systemctl status plexmediaserver
● plexmediaserver.service - Plex Media Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/plexmediaserver.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-04-30 17:08:20 PDT; 6min ago
    Process: 32081 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c /usr/bin/test -d "${PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_APPLICATION_SUPPORT_DIR}" || /bin/mkdir -p "${PLEX>
   Main PID: 32083 (Plex Media Serv)
      Tasks: 110 (limit: 19003)
     Memory: 261.8M
     CGroup: /system.slice/plexmediaserver.service
             ├─32083 /usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Plex Media Server
             ├─32168 Plex Plug-in [com.plexapp.system] /usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Resources/Plug-ins-b69929dab/Framework.bundle/Conte>
             ├─32232 /usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Plex Tuner Service /usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Resources/Tuner/Private /usr/lib/plexmedi>
             ├─32266 Plex Plug-in [com.plexapp.agents.thetvdb] /usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Resources/Plug-ins-b69929dab/Framework.bund>
             ├─32327 Plex Plug-in [com.plexapp.agents.themoviedb] /usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Resources/Plug-ins-b69929dab/Framework.b>
             ├─32373 Plex Plug-in [tv.plex.agents.music] /usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Resources/Plug-ins-b69929dab/Framework.bundle/Con>
             ├─32535 Plex Plug-in [com.plexapp.agents.plexthememusic] /usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Resources/Plug-ins-b69929dab/Framewo>
             ├─32595 Plex Plug-in [org.musicbrainz.agents.music] /usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Resources/Plug-ins-b69929dab/Framework.bu>
             └─32621 Plex Plug-in [com.plexapp.agents.imdb] /usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Resources/Plug-ins-b69929dab/Framework.bundle/>

Apr 30 17:08:20 dur systemd[1]: Starting Plex Media Server...
Apr 30 17:08:20 dur systemd[1]: Started Plex Media Server.
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ wget http://localhost:8888/web
--2020-04-30 17:14:53--  http://localhost:8888/web
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8888... failed: Connection refused.
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
thufir@dur:~$
```

This is towards streaming media to an Amazon Fire TV stick.

I've seen [mention](https://www.linode.com/docs/applications/media-servers/install-plex-media-server-on-ubuntu-18-04/) of using `ssh` initially:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ ssh thufir@192.168.1.23 -L 8888:localhost:32400
thufir@192.168.1.23's password: 

thufir@dur:~$
```

Comment: Simply open a web browser and point it to URL http://192.168.1.23:32400. Plex includes it's own web server. You configure Plex using the web page.

Comment: yes, thanks @user535733 I just found that:  http://localhost:32400/web